# When String object is created by concatenation of string literal variable and String?

Tags: java, string, substring, string-literals

```
public class SubString1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String s="Sachin";
String sb=s+"Tendulkar";
String sbc="SachinTendulkar";
System.out.println(sb==sbc);
}
}
```

Output : false.

Please Explain how the output is false??

I couldn't understand the logic behind this type of object creation. According to me both should refer to same instance and Answer should have been true. 
Please Explain.

Comment: How do you understand about Object memory?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427599/a-confusion-about-java-string-literal-pool-and-strings-concatenation) is a better duplicate.

Comment: Note that if you say `final String s="Sachin";` the result becomes `true`.  But you should still never use `==` to compare strings.

Comment: Sure. I never compare string using ==. This question was asked in an interview. So I need explanation for it.

Comment: The String `"SachinTendulkar"` is an object.  The String created by concatenating "Sachin" and "Tendulkar" is a different object.  They incidentally have the same value, but that has nothing to do with their "objectness", and `==` is comparing object addresses.

Answer (score 0):

They are different object references.  Strings in Java are immutable.

If you want to compare the actual content of the Strings, use the .equals method.

Comment: I want to understand the logic behind it. I agree with you that strings should be compared with equals() method.

Comment: Please Explain the logic, how it is happening in java???

Comment: @Randhishkumar The logic is that the code gets executed exactly as you see. There is no occult mechanism behind the scenes that causes `sb` to magically equal `sbc` when compared with the == operator. If you think there is, tell us what you think it is. It's a poorly phrased interview question, and not one that exhibits great competence or genuine interest on the part of the interviewer.